# Setting focus to input box in an InputDialog using MahApps

Tags: c#, focus, mahapps.metro

We've made our own search dialog based on the InputDialog from [MahApps Dialog examples](//github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/tree/master/MahApps.Metro/Themes/Dialogs), and it does work, but there are two issues with it:

1. When opened it does not automatically focus in the search field, so you have to click it before starting to type your search
2. If possible, we would like to autoselect the first entry in the list, so that you don't need to first select the entry in the list, and then hit the *OK* button

Can you help with either of these? The first is the most important, as the users start typing quite often before noticing that the focus is not in the search field.

Comment: Can you provide some code so we can assist?

Comment: Code is mostly copy-and-paste from the examples link provided.

Comment: Sorry if the question and answer looks like I haven't done my homework and searched for solutions, which I do have. I just discovered the typo/mismatch when copying out to start a new dialog based on the original search dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with providing some code excerpts to get help, which was basically a copy-and-paste from the example link I provided in the question, I discovered there was a dependency between the class name and the title of the dialog.

```
<dialogs:BaseMetroDialog x:Class="Some.Path.Dialogs.SearchDialog"
  ...
  d:DesignHeight="500" d:DesignWidth="800" 
  Title="SearchDialog" Background="White">
  ...
</dialogs:BaseMetroDialog>
```

When the `Title` matched the last part of `Class` the focus was set properly. Regarding the auto-select, that turns out not be related to the Metro.MahApps interface, but only internal code, and I found an entry point which sounds promising to get my achieved goal.